# Cyclic package dependency while implementing proc macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I try to implement a proc_macro `Dump`, which is similar to serdes `Serialize`.

For this purpose I have a crate `foo` which contains my "primitive" structs (`P1` and `P2` in this case) which should only be dumpable.

Next I do have a `foo_derive` crate which contains the procedural macro itself.

Because I want to support multiple formats I have a third crate `foo_dump` which contains the trait definition of `Dump` (e.g. this struct can be dumped) and `Dumper` (this is something the backend should implement).
Very straight forward until this point.

When I now want to compile it, I get this error:

```
$ cargo build
error: cyclic package dependency: package `foo v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.u34pI5J6qd/example/foo)` depends on itself. Cycle:
package `foo v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.u34pI5J6qd/example/foo)`
    ... which is depended on by `foo_dump v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.u34pI5J6qd/example/foo_dump)`
    ... which is depended on by `foo_derive v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.u34pI5J6qd/example/foo_derive)`
```

I don't know what the correct way is, how to use dependencies in this crate. My current one is:

[image: dependencies]

and this certainly is not possible.

What am I missing? What do I have to do to break the dependency circle?

---

([mcve@github](https://github.com/hellow554/proc_macro_mcve/tree/82565739105dc5bf22da25efee189b9118bf89cb))

*/Cargo.toml*

```
[workspace]
members = [ 
    "foo",
    "foo_derive",
    "foo_dump",
]
```

*/foo/Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
foo_derive = { path = "../foo_derive" }
```

*/foo/src/lib.rs*

```
use foo_derive::Dump;

struct P1;
struct P2;

#[derive(Dump)]
struct Bar {
    primitive_one: P1,
    primitive_two: P2,
}
```

*/foo_dump/Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "foo_dump"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
foo = { path = "../foo" }
```

*/foo_dump/src/lib.rs*

```
use foo::{P1, P2};

pub trait Dumper {
    fn dump_p1(&mut self, value: &P1);
    fn dump_p2(&mut self, value: &P2);
}

pub trait Dump {
    fn dump<D: Dumper>(&self, d: D);
}

impl Dump for P1 {
    fn dump<D: Dumper>(&self, d: D) {
        d.dump_p1(self);
    }
}

impl Dump for P2 {
    fn dump<D: Dumper>(&self, d: D) {
        d.dump_p2(self);
    }
}
```

*/foo_derive/Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "foo_derive"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
syn = "*"
quote = "*"
foo_dump = { path = "../foo_dump" }
```

*/foo_derive/src/lib.rs*

```
extern crate proc_macro;

use quote::quote;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use syn::DeriveInput;

#[proc_macro_derive(Dump)]
pub fn derive_dump(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let name = &input.ident;

    quote!(
        impl foo_dump::Dump for #name {
            fn dump<D: foo_dump::Dumper>(&self, d: D) {
                unimplemented!()
            }
        }
    ).into()
}
```

Comment: Your derive crate should not depend of anything because it only handles code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Boiethious comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088182/cyclic-package-dependency-while-implementing-proc-macro#comment95009805_54088182) and his help [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/conversation/54088182) I was able to come up with a solution, which involes introducing a new crate `foo_core` which contains the structs `P1` and `P2`.

So what I did was:

- Removing `P1` and `P2` from `foo` and putting them into `foo_core`
- Removing the dependency `foo_dump` from `foo_derive` so it only depends on `syn` and `quote` anymore
- Adding `foo_core` as a dependency in `foo` and `foo_dump`
- Adding the dependency `foo_dump` to `foo`

(you can see the full list of changes in the [git history](https://github.com/hellow554/proc_macro_mcve/commit/0a3953cfbd0efbd8331b9d2a76288b6b6e1cef28)).

The final dependency chain now looks like this:

[image: depency graph]

Comment: If you have a better solution, please feel free to create one! I am interested in any solution available.

Comment: Is foo_core needed? You can put the stuff in foo_dump

Comment: Interesting... I think one could put the stuff I need in `foo_dump`. I have to look at my real world example, but yes, that would be a simpler approach.